# why can't shift the second value?

Tags: perl

I feel confused about my little perl script.
I have passed two values to a routin, however, just the first one works in the subroutin.

```
#!usr/bin/perl 
sub even_number_printer_gen {
    my ( $input1, $input2 ) = @_;

    #my $input1=shift;
    #my $input2=shift;
    print
        "after shifting, the input1 is $input1 and the input2 is $input2\n";
    if ( $input1 % 2 ) { $input1++ }
    if ( $input2 % 2 ) { $input2++ }

    $rs = sub {    #subroutin 1, everytime add 2 in $input1
        print "$input1 ";
        $input1 += 2;
    };
    $rs2 = sub {    #subroutin 2, everytime add 3 in $input2
        print "$input2 ";
        $ipnut2 += 3;
    };
    @rs3 = ( $rs, $rs2 );
    return @rs3;    #return two subroutins as an array
}
@iterator = &even_number_printer_gen( 31, 20 );
for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    &{ $iterator[0] };    #refer subroutin 1
    &{ $iterator[1] };    #refer subroutin 2
    print "\n";
}
print "done!\n";
```

the output is

```
after shifting, the input1 is 31 and the input2 is 20
32 20 
34 20 
36 20 
38 20 
40 20 
42 20 
44 20 
46 20 
48 20 
50 20 
done!
```

Why  the second value doesn't change?

Comment: Perl basic diagnostics: 1: `use strict;` `use warnings;`. 2: reformat your code with perltidy, so it's  clear where blocks begin and end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
$ipnut2 += 3;
```

Ought to be:

```
$input2 += 3;
```

On my computer

```
f.jardon@xxxxx 11:49:04 ~/tmp
$ cat fixedperl.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub even_number_printer_gen {
    my ( $input1, $input2 ) = @_;

    #my $input1=shift;
    #my $input2=shift;
    print
        "after shifting, the input1 is $input1 and the input2 is $input2\n";
    if ( $input1 % 2 ) { $input1++ }
    if ( $input2 % 2 ) { $input2++ }

    $rs = sub {    #subroutin 1, everytime add 2 in $input1
        print "$input1 ";
        $input1 += 2;
    };
    $rs2 = sub {    #subroutin 2, everytime add 3 in $input2
        print "$input2 ";
        $input2 += 3; ## <<<<====================== HERE IS THE FIX
    };
    @rs3 = ( $rs, $rs2 );
    return @rs3;    #return two subroutins as an array
}
@iterator = &even_number_printer_gen( 31, 20 );
for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    &{ $iterator[0] };    #refer subroutin 1
    &{ $iterator[1] };    #refer subroutin 2
    print "\n";
}
print "done!\n";

f.jardon@xxxxx 11:49:06 ~/tmp
$ ./fixedperl.pl
after shifting, the input1 is 31 and the input2 is 20
32 20
34 23
36 26
38 29
40 32
42 35
44 38
46 41
48 44
50 47
done!
```

Comment: And if @Sandy had included `use strict;` at the top of the script, Perl would have printed out an error message *Global symbol "$ipnut2" requires explicit package name at line XXX* to make it super-obvious where the error was.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Doesn't my answer correctly explain `why doesn't the second routine works` ?

Comment: _Didn't you mean_ is asking a question of OP, not giving an answer. If you want it to be an answer, then it should be _Change x to y_

Comment: @StephenMuecke The fact it is a question doesn't prevent it from [providing an answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method).

Comment: @fjardon Hi, I don't understand why the second value keep 20 all the time.

Comment: @Sandy did you fix your code as I suggested ? I still see the error in your question and when applying the fix I recommended I cannot reproduce your bug.

Comment: @fjardon Hi,there, thank you very much. It is a typo, sorry for my careless.

Comment: @fjardon Hi, there, would you mind recommend me an IDE for perl?

Comment: @Sandy I mostly program in a terminal so I use emacs or vim but I wouldn't recommend it as a beginner's IDE (event though they **are** powerful tools).

Comment: vim works fine with syntax highlighting. On Windows, I use TextPad and some custom macros to run perl -c, perltidy, perl -MO=Deparse etc.